# different result with jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with id: param0.typeParameter.

I try to get it with jquery with:

```
$('#param0.typeParameter');
```

i get nothing but if it use this

```
document.getElementById('param0.typeParameter');
```

that work

Comment: typeParameter is supposed to be a css class ?

Comment: whats the difference? Maybe the ».« is no good idea…

Comment: You should just avoid using dot in your `id` name. Dot are used to define a class

Comment: It's the spring way to manage a class with many field

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make jQuery select element with ID `param0.typeParameter` instead of element with ID `param0` and class name `typeParameter` you should use the following:

```
$('#param0\\.typeParameter');
```

#### Official Proof

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   ``` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^``{|}~ ``` ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with
>   `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

**SOURCE:** http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LtRxg/

Answer (score 10):

You can try this instead:

```
$('[id="param0.typeParameter"]');
```

Or else the code assumes you want to select an element with id `param0` and class `typeParameter`

Comment: I believe this makes it a generic attribute selector that will be magnitudes slower than a selector with a properly escaped period that can make use of retrieving the element by its ID.

Comment: Hmmm that may be true @Deadron but how slow is "slow"? Is it really that noticeable?

Comment: also, it's selecting an element by id. Since there should only be one of them, you likely only need to perform this once or twice, meaning even if the difference in speed was large, it likely won't be noticeable.

Comment: @qwertynl While it is obviously implementation specific an ID selection can be assumed to be a constant time operation while a attribute selector would have to scan the document.  Depending on the size of your document and the number of times the selector is executed it could have an impact that is trivially avoided.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery uses the CSS-selector language. Which causes `"#param0.typeParameter"` to be interpretted as an element with id `param0` and class `typeParameter`.

The jQuery statement is more similar to:

```
document.querySelector("#param0.typeParameter");
```

Comment: This is not the solution but the best answer cause of the explanation !!